# FileConfigurationProvider FileNotFoundException

Tags: .net-core-3.1

I'm trying to load ini file with IniConfigurationProvider like this (using net core 3.1)

```
var config = @"D:\config.ini";
Console.WriteLine(File.Exists(config));   //true
var configProvider = new IniConfigurationProvider(
    new IniConfigurationSource() {
        Path = config
    }
);
configProvider.Load();
```

but it throws FileNotFoundException

```
Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The configuration file 'D:\config.ini' was not found and is not optional.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load(Boolean reload)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load()
   at MyProgram.Program.ThreadProc() in d:\apps\Program.cs:line 39
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

`File.Exists` prints `true`, so why is it throughing the exception then?

Answer (score 1):

IniConfigurationSource doesn't support full path to config file. You must use only file name. And add file provider.

```
var configProvider = new IniConfigurationProvider(
    new IniConfigurationSource() {
        Path = "config.ini",
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider("D:\\")
    }
);
configProvider.Load();
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume it is a bug because the stream overload works correctly

```
configProvider.Load(File.OpenRead(config));
```